# Get the Multiple Data onclick event using ajax at search time on different input field

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am searching data using Ajax. When I search the data I got the result and click one of theme (data1). And got clickable data on same searching input box. But I also want to put the other data (data2) on the other input field at the same click on the event and want to get data1 and also data2 but I got an error.

Ajax script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 fetch_customer_data();
 function fetch_customer_data(query = '')
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"{{ URL::to('/searchCity') }}",
   method:'GET',
   data:{query:query},
   dataType:'json',
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#result').html(data.table_data);

    $('#total_records').text(data.total_data);
   }
  })
 }
 $(document).on('keyup', '#searchCity', function(){
  var query = $(this).val();
  fetch_customer_data(query);
 });
 $(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
    $('#searchCity').val($(this).data('name'));
    $('#searchCityCode').val($(this).data('code'));
    $('#result').empty()
         var name = $('#searchCityCode').val(); 
                alert(name);

});
});

<input type="text" name="searchCity" id="searchCity" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for a city or particular hotel" style="" value="">

<input type="text" name="searchCityCode" id="searchCityCode" class="form-control"  style="" value="">
```

Controller

```
public function searchCitylist(Request $request)
    {
     if($request->ajax())
     {
      $output = '';
      $query = $request->get('query');
      if($query != '')
      {
      $userreg = DB::table('cityarea')->distinct()->
        where('City_Code', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')->
        orWhere('City_Name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')->  
        orWhere('Destination_Code', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')->   
        orWhere('Country_Code', 'like', '%'.$query.'%') 
         ->get();         
      }   
      $total_row = $userreg->count();
      if($total_row > 0)
      {
        foreach($userreg as $userregs) 
        { 
        $output .= '        
        <tr>
         <td class="item" data-name="'.$userregs->City_Name.'">'.$userregs->City_Name.'</td>
  <td class="item" data-code="'.$userregs->City_Code.'">'.$userregs->City_Code.'</td>      
         </tr>';            
            } 
        } 
        else { $output = 'No Data Found';               
             }            
      $userreg = array(
       'table_data'  => $output,
       'total_data'  => $total_row
      );
      echo json_encode($userreg);     
     }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added `item` class for `td` element, during the on-click event `this` var will contain only the anyone `data-` attribute values.

So, better you can add the class name with all data attribute values for `tr` like below

```
$output .= '<tr class="item" data-code="'.$userregs->City_Code.'" data-name="'.$userregs->City_Name.'">
    <td>'.$userregs->City_Name.'</td>
    <td>'.$userregs->City_Code.'</td>
    </tr>';
```

Refer - http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5